# How to map a route for specific action in C# ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need your help, I have no experience how route works.

Now, I have the following urls:

```
http://website.com/controller1/action1
http://website.com/controller1/action2
```

The question, how to route to another url for `http://website.com/controller1/action1` without affecting the url to `http://website.com/controller1/action2`

Means:

When access `http://website.com/controller1/action1`, I want to show url: `http://website.com/shortcut`, but for `http://website.com/controller1/action2` to show same as `http://website.com/controller1/action2`.

It is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add route like to `routeCollection` in file `Global.aspx` add to method `RegisterRoutes`

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "shortcut",
    url: "shortcut",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller1", action = "action1" }
);
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that this should go *above* the default route (first match gets served, if this is put below the default route it might never be reached)

Comment: I put above default route, i know this rule :)

Answer (score 0):

The default route in a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application will handle your first two requests, but you may be confused about the naming convention. For example, if you have a controller class named `HomeController` and an action named `action1` inside it, the default handling of that route would be `/Home/action1`.

To handle `/controller1/action1` and `/controller1/action2`, you would need to literally name your controller class `controller1Controller` and add two actions e.g.

```
public class controller1Controller : Controller
{
    public ActionResult action1()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult action2()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

To handle your `/shortcut` route, you can use what Satpal suggested as long as it's defined *above* the default route. The more specific the route, the earlier in your route definitions it needs to appear e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "nameOfShortcutRoute",
    url: "shortcut",
    defaults: new { controller = "controller1", action = "action1" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Check out this link for a good Routing tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs